# Bring back the "newest" tab on the users page

Tags: feature-request, users-page

The traditional users page has recently been replaced by a more dynamic reputation-league-style page. While I welcome this change in general, I would like to have the "newest" tab back.

While I agree that for example the "oldest" tab served little purpose, the newest tab can be useful: For example if you want to keep track of the rate with which new users sign up on a beta site (or if you want to see whether a recent blog post/reddit post/whatever caused an increase in sign ups or whether a friend you've been nagging to sign up has done so yet).

So I propose that in the addition to the league-style tabs, there should also be a "newest" tab which sorts the user by the date they registered, newest first.

Comment: I see the new users tab is back, but it is not sorted by join date.

Answer (score 2):

Whether this came and went, it's back with the ability to [sort "new users" based on "creation date"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate):

[image]

"New users" are defined as those "who joined in the last 45 days".

Of course, [the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/298468/new-users-sorted-by-creation-date) will also do the trick (with a bit of a delay from data in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com)):

```sql
select Id, DisplayName, CreationDate
from Users
where DateDiff("d",CreationDate,getdate()) <= 45
order by CreationDate desc;
```